# Problematic installation (compilation) of OpenCV 3.1.0 in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, compiling, opencv

I am trying to install the OpenCV 3.1.0 library and I am getting this error after I run `make`:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5402,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
             from /home/alex/opencv/OpenCV/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h:55,
             from /home/alex/opencv/OpenCV/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts.hpp:28,
             from /home/alex/opencv/OpenCV/build/modules/core/perf_precomp.hpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

I have tried numerous times to (re)install different versions of `libstdc++`, thinking that the problems stems from here and I have double checked the needed dependencies, but to no avail.

I have also looked in `/usr/include/c++/6/` folder and the file (`stdlib.h`) mentioned in the error are there.

I should also mention that running (before `make`):

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON
```

gives failed results on:

```
HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Is `/usr/include/stdlib.h` present? is package `libc6-dev` installed correctly (`dpkg --audit libc6-dev`)?

Comment: @steeldriver: `/usr/include/stdlib.h` exists and `libc6-dev is already the newest version`

Comment: OK so this appears to be a known issue: [GCC 6.0/6.x build problems #6517](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6517) I suggest you try some of the workarounds suggested there e.g. adding `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` to your `cmake` command

Comment: @steeldriver: `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - feel free to write an answer (I tried, but I don't understand the issue well enough to write a good one)